# How to prove minimax with normal distribution.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X$ be a sample from $N_p(\theta,I_p)$ with unknown $\theta\in \mathcal{R}^p$.

Consider the estimation of $\theta$ under the loss function $$L(\theta,T)\,=\,\|T-\mathcal\theta\|^2\,=\,\sum_{i=1}^{p}(T_i-\mathcal{\theta_i}
)^2,$$ with independent priors for $\theta_i$'s.

How to show that $X$ is minimax of $\theta$?

My thought is:

${{R}_{X}}(\theta )=E[L(\theta ,a)]=E[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}{{{({{\theta }_{i}}-{{X}_{i}})}^{2}}}]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}{E(\theta _{i}^{2}-2{{\theta }_{i}}{{X}_{i}}+X_{i}^{2})}=p$. $E(\mathbf{\theta_i}|X_i)$ is $\psi-$bayes rule w.r.t.$\Pi$, with $\psi$ being the class of rules $T(X)$ satisfying $E[T(X)]^2\le\infty$ for any $\theta$. Since $E[E(\mathbf{\theta}_i|X_i)]=\theta_i=E(X_i)$, $X_i$ is bayes estimator with constant risk. So $X_i$ is minimax, hence$X$ is minimax.

But I don't know if It's correct or not, eg whether we can derive that $X$ is Bayes estimator?.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your thoughts ?

Comment: hi, i have updated my thought

Comment: $X$ cannot be a Bayes estimator because it is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. However, $X$ is a limit of Bayes estimators with respect to a sequence of priors (see Theorem 2 and example 2 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_estimator#Least_favorable_distribution)). This, combined with the fact that it has constant risk, makes it a minimax estimator of $\theta$.

Comment: It's quite useful! thank you very much